# Timers Tick event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

There is a simple code in which I added a timer and generated tick event but the event is not firing.

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="True" EnableViewState="True" ViewStateMode="Inherit" ClientIDMode="Inherit"></asp:Timer>



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        setImageurl();
        //Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
        //Timer1.Interval = 1000;
    }
}
void setImageurl()
{
    Random _rand = new Random();
    int i = _rand.Next(1, 4);
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/ImagesSlideshow/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setImageurl();
}
```

I dont know why this is happening. Help me out.

Comment: Ok, can you [edit] your question to reflect the Timer is enabled and where you're doing it, thanks

Comment: I have done editing

Comment: What happens if the page loads completely in a time shorter than the tick interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `EnableCdn="true"` on the `ScriptManager` and it will work, just tried it on my side:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableCdn="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do we have to add anything important when we use ajax extensions ?@DenisWessels

Comment: It's working on my side.Place a break point on setImageurl() and make sure the break point is being hit.Also make sure you have images called 1.jpg 2.jpg and 3.jpg inside the ImagesSlideshow folder

Comment: no that statement is not getting hit. and those images are present in the folder. thanks.

Comment: Inspect the browser console and let us know if you see any errors.To bring up the browser console in Google Chrome press Ctrl+Shift+J

Comment: thanx, learnt new way of finding errors. thing is working now.

Comment: This worked for me, but if anyone looks at this again - I've used this a ton of times, never had to do this.  Why now?  I did create a web application and move files over from a different project, but everything else seems to be working.  I looked it up, don't see that anything about scripts is different, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb you have to set `Timer1.Enabled=true` for a Timer control to fire it's Tick() event.